# "Chapter" appearing at the start of every chapter

Tags: chapters

I'm using a [template from a website](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/durham-university-thesis), and every time a new chapter starts, 'Chapter 3' for example appears and its quite absurd. How do I edit this feature out of the code?

Comment: Have you tried using `\chapter*{Chapter title}`?

Comment: @Werner First thing I tried, but this also excludes it from the table of contents which I did not want

Comment: Are you saying that the chapter number does not change?

Comment: @Sigur At the start of every chapter in the main body, theres a big line of text saying "Chapter 4" for example.

Comment: The typical solution here is to use `\chapter*{Chapter title}\addtocontents{toc}{chapter}{Chapter title}`, but this can be automated. Can you please provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that shows your current setup... it's just easier to see whether this might conflict with a solution rather than giving you something that might not work right away.

Comment: Are you writing a thesis somewhere other than Durham University? There's a chance that you'll end up having to redo most or all of the Durham formatting to satisfy your university's requirements. If you're not writing a thesis, then why use a thesis document class?

Comment: @MikeRenfro Its for an undergraduate final year project, ive taken that template and basically redone it already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `dmathesis` which is based on the standard `report` document class and keeps the standard definitions for formatting chapter headings, so you can use the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package:

```
\documentclass{dmathesis}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test chapter one}
\chapter[Two]{Test chapter two}

\end{document}
```

If you don't want to load `titlesec`, you can redefine `\@makechaptertitle`:

```
\documentclass{dmathesis}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
%    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
%        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
    %    \par\nobreak
%        \vskip 20\p@
%    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test chapter one}
\chapter[Two]{Test chapter two}

\end{document}
```

In both cases the table of contents is:

[image]

and the first page of the first chapter is:

[image]

As you can see, the full functionality of \chapter is preserved (you have the optional argument for an eventual different entry in the ToC and headers and also marks are appropriately generated).

Another option would be to patch the command with the help of, for example, [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox).

Answer (score 4):

The following addition using [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) forces chapters to be seen as a starred chapter:

[image]

```
\documentclass{dmathesis}
\usepackage{xparse}

\let\oldchapter\chapter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{s o m}{%
  \oldchapter*{#3}%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
    {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#3}}%
    {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2}}}    

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter[A test chapter]{Test chapter}

\end{document}
```

One advantage is that it still allows for a different ToC entry for each chapter using `\chapter[<ToC entry>]{<Body entry>}`.

Comment: Doesn't this destroy the marking mechanism for (eventual) headers?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Yes; those definition can be added to the updated `\chapter` command. For example, adding `\chaptermark{<*>}` in either of the conditional location will restore the usual chapter marks.